# What is best way to put a flag so I can determine to connect database nomally or restore from backup?

Tags: java, derby

Have an application running and user can select normal backup or automatic backup of database.
Everything is running good except one thing...
If user wants to restore from backup database
How could I achieve that?
For example

```
if(a){Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:dbER;create=true");}
else{"jdbc:derby:dbER;restoreFrom=PATH");}
```

What could be "a" as a decision maker?

public class ConnectDatabase {

```
private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"; 
private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:dbER;create=true";
//private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:dbER;restoreFrom=/Applications/ER/dbER";

//static private Connection conn;
static Connection conn;
static private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
prepareInsert PI = new prepareInsert();

public ConnectDatabase() {

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        if (conn != null){
            //System.out.println("Connedted to database");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for the format of question...this statement is right at the start of application so, I couldn't use database to get status of user's selection(normal or restore)...

Comment: It's just not the format. The code you've posted would not compile and does not make sense.

Comment: Like I said I have complete working code and application running fine

Comment: Just used for question purposes... hope you understand.... these characters limits ....

Comment: is there a way to edit questions?     like edit comments...

Answer (score 0):

I'd be wary of automating a restore of your database from a backup. Restoring your database from a backup seems like an infrequent, unusual, special scenario.

Note that, among other things, it's quite a **destructive** operation, because you lose all the data in your current database, it gets replaced by the data from the backup!

I think that a sophisticated user of your program might be able to decide that they wanted to perform such a restore, but I think it's best to ensure that it will be a human making that decision, you should not try to encode it as an algorithm that makes that decision for the human.

Comment: Thanks for the advice  only using this feature when automatic backup is enabled     Problem solved